# Changing Class Variable Capitalization in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, class, interface, styles, codeblocks

SO I've been using Code::Blocks for awhile now, and I've experienced this annoying thing for quite awhile now. When you're creating a new class, it has the following setup page:

[image]

In the "Add new" section, we can, of course, add new variables and include "Getter" and "Setter" methods. So we add a few variables, and create a new class:

[image]

But here's where the problem occurs; when the getter and setter methods are added, they are named by default as "Getname" and "Setname." My question is: is there anyway to change it to be, by default "getName" and "setName?" (Note the change of capitalization). Or, on the other hand, should I be changing my coding style to match that of Code::Blocks? Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this is done on purpose
http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Coding_style